# How to change main image slider using thumbnail image on click in react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I had Created an E-commerce app like Flipkart moreover I have to create the product image. Whenever I click on the bottom thumbnail image the main image needs to be changed dynamically.  I have attached the screenshot here for the reference.

[image: Screnshot reference]

Comment: any code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: till no idea,ho to do